# What is the meaning of "our time together "had come to a close."?

Tags: meaning

Don received a letter from one of his wives and reading it to his friend Winston:

> "I decided to go through with the pregnancy, and I had a baby, a son.
>   "Your son. "I decided  to raise him by myself because **our time
>   together "had come to a close.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Come to a close](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+a+close)*** is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> To reach an end point.
>
> - *If there are no other issues to discuss, then this meeting can come to a close. The play's lengthy run on Broadway comes to a close tonight.*

(The Free Dictionary)

She is saying that she has decided to keep the baby and raise him by herself, (without the father) as their relationship is over.